# How to indentify the target user in the team.integrationLogs api event log?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm using the team.integrationLogs API to track when a user has access or not and it is working fine when i test for my own user. The problem is that i can revoke access of an another account and i need to know what account it is (the target).

Here is an example of logs when i (gabriel.verle) remove the access of another account (fizz.buzz):

```
    {
        "user_id": "U0585MT1F97",
        "user_name": "gabriel.verle",
        "date": 1705067563,
        "change_type": "removed",
        "reason": "user_revoked_auth",
        "app_type": "Miro",
        "app_id": "A8VK125AS",
        "scope": "identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar,identify,groups:read,im:read,users:read,users:read.email,chat:write,links:read,links:write"
    }
```

So how would i get the username or userId of the user that i remove access?